# Creating dynamic and expandable dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

I want to create a Python dictionary which holds values in a multidimensional array that can expand.

This is the structure that the values should be stored:

```
userdata = {'data':[{'username':'Ronny Leech','age':'22','country':'Siberia'},{'username':'Cronulla James','age':'34','country':'USA'}]}
```

Let's say I want to add another user:

```
def user_list():
     users = []
     for i in xrange(5, 0, -1):
       lonlatuser.append(('username','%s %s' % firstn, lastn))
       lonlatuser.append(('age',age))
       lonlatuser.append(('country',country))
     return dict(user)
```

This will only return a dictionary with a single value in it (since the key names are same values will overwritten). So how do I append a set of values to this dictionary?

Note: assume `age`, `firstn`, `lastn`, and `country` are dynamically generated.

Comment: lontatuser is the list in userdata with key data? And what is the user you put in dict?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
userdata = { "data":[]}

def fil_userdata():
  for i in xrange(0,5):
    user = {}
    user["name"]=...
    user["age"]=...
    user["country"]=...
    add_user(user)

def add_user(user):
  userdata["data"].append(user)
```

or shorter:

```
def gen_user():
  return {"name":"foo", "age":22}

userdata = {"data": [gen_user() for i in xrange(0,5)]}

# or fill separated from declaration so you can fill later
userdata ={"data":None} # None: not initialized
userdata["data"]=[gen_user() for i in xrange(0,5)]
```

Comment: I used it within a single function, stacked up as a single unit so then I can re-use it. Thanks.

Comment: In Python 3, ``xrange`` can be replaced by ``range``

Answer (score 14):

I think it's too late for the answer but nevertheless, hoping that it may help somebody in near future I'm gonna give the answer. Let's say I have a list and I wanna make them as a dictionary. The first element of each of the sublists is the key and the second element is the value. I want to store the key value dynamically. Here is an example:

```
dict= {} # create an empty dictionary
list= [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['a', 3], ['c', 4]]
#list is our input where 'a','b','c', are keys and 1,2,3,4 are values
for i in range(len(list)):
     if list[i][0] in dic.keys():# if key is present in the list, just append the value
         dic[list[i][0]].append(list[i][1])
     else:
         dic[list[i][0]]= [] # else create a empty list as value for the key
         dic[list[i][0]].append(list[i][1]) # now append the value for that key
```

Output:

```
{'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2], 'c': [4]}
```

Comment: I presume the references to 'dic' are supposed to be 'dict' as declared on the first line.

Comment: I would suggest not to name your variables the type they have.

Answer (score 11):

You can create a list of keys first and by iterating keys, you can store values in the dictionary

```
l=['name','age']

d = {}

for i in l:
    k = input("Enter Name of key")
    d[i]=k   


print("Dictionary is : ",d)
```

output :

```
Enter Name of key kanan
Enter Name of key34
Dictionary is :  {'name': 'kanan', 'age': '34'}
```

Answer (score 2):

What's the purpose of the outer `data` dict?

One possibility is not to use `username` as a key, but rather the username itself.

It seems like you are trying to use dicts as a database, but I'm not sure it's a good fit.

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer to the OP. Down voted

Answer (score 1):

You could try this 
Python 3+

```
key_ref = 'More Nested Things'
my_dict = {'Nested Things': 
                [{'name', 'thing one'}, {'name', 'thing two'}]}

my_list_of_things = [{'name', 'thing three'}, {'name', 'thing four'}]

try:
    # Try and add to the dictionary by key ref
    my_dict[key_ref].append(my_list_of_things)

except KeyError:
    # Append new index to currently existing items
    my_dict = {**my_dict, **{key_ref: my_list_of_things}}

print(my_dict)

output:
{
    'More Nested Things': [{'name', 'thing three'}, {'name', 'thing four'}], 
    'Nested Things': [{'thing one', 'name'}, {'name', 'thing two'}]
}
```

You could rap this in your on definition and make it more user friendly, typing try catch it fairly tedious

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question directly, to add another user to your 'database':

```
 newUser = {'username':'Joe Dirt','age':'70','country':'Antarctica'}

 userdata['data'].append(newUser)
```