# How to get the desired value of the dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

First off, i'm new to python and trying to create a dynamic dictionary :

```
editdistances = { r.name  :  editdistance.eval(baseline.result, r.result)}
```

note that i'm running a `for r in values:` above `r`  having 2 instances name and value.Now the thing is i want to append the value part(editdistance.eval(baseline.result, r.result) in a table

```
table.append(editdistances[x])
```

this is what i tried but pretty sure it's wrong because it's not referencing the value. How can i fix it and still know what's the name `(r.name)` of each value in the table.

**Edit:** Just noticed another issue in `editdistances = { r.name  :  editdistance.eval(baseline.result, r.result)}` basically let's say i have 3 students, student1,student 2 and student 3. And i want to input 3 grades for each one at a time using a loop, basically first iteration student1 :16..second iteration student1:16 student2 :12..third iteration student1:16 student2 :12 student3:9..4th iteration student1:16,7 student2 :12 student3:9 ...and so on, how can i do that and still be able to refer to each grade indivudually assuming each refers to a different course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
editdistances = { 'r.name'  :  "editdistance.eval(baseline.result, r.result)"}
table=[]
for r in editdistances:
    table.append(editdistances[r])
print (table)
```

Output

```
['editdistance.eval(baseline.result, r.result)']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value for a given key in a dictionary this way (assuming r has a property values:

```
for value in r.values:
    table.append(editdistances[value])
```

If values is a method of r then you also need to add brackets:

```
for value in r.values():
    table.append(editdistances[value])
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like you're asking how to use a dictionary.

"how can i do that and still be able to refer to each grade indivudually assuming each refers to a different course"

Create a dictionary with each student as a key in the first level. 
Then each student is a dictionary, with a course-name for keys, and the grades attached as values:

```
students = {
            'student1' : {'class1' : 'grade1', 'class2' : 'grade2', 'class3' : grade3'},
            'student2' : {'class1' : 'grade1', 'class2' : 'grade2', 'class3' : grade3'},
            'student3' : {'class1' : 'grade1', 'class2' : 'grade2', 'class3' : grade3'}
           }

for student in students:
    for class_name in student:
        # print the student's name, class name, and their grade for that class.
        print (student, class_name, students[student][class_name])
```

Given your current question, the question itself isn't written that clearly
And you have dependency code/data-structuring that you mention briefly but don't allow to be fully described.

Please provide that dependency code so we can see what you're talking about.  For example, the sentence "I am doing this in a for loop" is way more characters than 
just pasting the exact and original code.

Comment: That code doesn't address my issue as i'm looking to fill the dictionary automatically and your function just supplied the values statically.

Comment: Your question says "get the desired value."  not "populate/insert/set," which is why I said it wasn't written clearly.  You also have some typos in your code, and don't define the desired end-result data structure you're looking for, or what the operations are for the methods you're using in your code. 

 Furthermore, this question may be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468334/python-how-to-create-dynamic-and-expandable-dictionaries