# Make List and Dictionaries dynamically in Python. I am trying to create the array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am new in Python and getting the problem in creating the dynamically list and dictionaries.

I want the result like:

```
{
'page1':
    [{'email':
        [{'emailAddress':'abc@gmail.com'}],[{'emailAddress1':'abc@gmail.com1'}],...
    }],[{'url':
        [{'url':'abc.com','cordinates','10,10,100,45'}],[{'url':'abc.com','cordinates','10,10,100,45'}]...
    }]
}
{
'page1':
    [{'email':
        [{'emailAddress':'abc@gmail.com'}],[{'emailAddress1':'abc@gmail.com1'}],...
    }],[{'url':
        [{'url':'abc.com','cordinates','10,10,100,45'}],[{'url':'abc.com','cordinates','10,10,100,45'}]...
    }]
}
{
'page1':
    [{'email':
        [{'emailAddress':'abc@gmail.com'}],[{'emailAddress1':'abc@gmail.com1'}],...
    }],[{'url':
        [{'url':'abc.com','cordinates','10,10,100,45'}],[{'url':'abc.com','cordinates','10,10,100,45'}]...
    }]
}.....
```

I cannot give you the original data for review but I am going to create this type of the data using the code below:

```
from pprint import pprint
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
dict3 = {}

newObj = {'name'}
finalVar = []
finalVars = []
newVal = {}
for i in range(10):
    temp = {'page'+str(i)}

    for k in range(10):
        newtemp = {'page'+str(i):{'email':[{
            'emailId':str(i),
            'test':str(k)
        }]}}
        finalVar.append(newtemp)

for i in range(10):
    temp = {'page'+str(i)}
    for k in range(10):
        newtemp = {'page'+str(i):{'email':[{
            'url':str(i),
            'testing':str(k)
        }]}}
        finalVars.append(newtemp)

pprint(finalVars)
```

I am new in Python so, even I don't know that I am creating the valid list and array dictionary. So, please sorry if there is any thing wrong.

Comment: I need this type of array because I have to use this array in XLSX writer.

Comment: temp object is never used, also I think it spelled "coordinates", with double O

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python | How to create dynamic and expandable dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468334/python-how-to-create-dynamic-and-expandable-dictionaries)

Comment: temp object is never used. I didn't get you. You mean we can't use temp as a variable?

Comment: `temp` is not an invalid name. Please can you explain your problem more clearly? What is wrong with your current code and what assistance are you asking for?

Comment: Actually, I am working on getting the emails and url's from PDF and their co-ordinate values. All the data I have but not in a good way means not the formatted data. I need to make the valid list and dictionary so that I can put the data in excel sheet using XLSX writer in Python.

Comment: @VikashDhiman What @AzatIbrakov meant is that after defining the variable `temp` you never again use it, making it useless.  Of course `temp` is a valid variable name.

Comment: @Quaternion ahh I got it. Actually I am PHP developer. So, I was trying to create array like we create the array in PHP. So, I left it as it is. Yeah this one was not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something similar to the following code will generate the type of array you desire.

```
email_entries = []
for i in range(num_email_entries):
    email_entries.append([{'emailAddress' + str(i)*(i>0):'abc@gmail.com'}])
email_container = [{'email':tuple(email_entries)}]

url_entries = []
for i in range(num_url_entries):
    url_entries.append([{'url' + str(i)*(i>0):'abc.com',
                       'coordinates' + str(i)*(i>0):'10,10,100,45'}])
url_container = [{'url':tuple(url_entries)}]

array = {'page': (email_container,url_container)}
```

The output when `num_email_entries = num_url_entries = 2` is

```
{'page': 
       ([{'email': 
                  ([{'emailAddress': 'abc@gmail.com'}], 
                   [{'emailAddress1': 'abc@gmail.com'}])
        }],
        [{'url': 
                  ([{'url': 'abc.com', 
                      'coordinates': '10,10,100,45'}], 
                   [{'url1': 'abc.com', 
                      'coordinates1': '10,10,100,45'}])
        }]
       )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the question I am assuming that a dictionary is needed whose keys are *page0, page1* and so on, and value of each key is another dictionary with keys as *emails, urls* and value of *emails* is an array of dicts like `{'email': '0@mail.com'}` and value of *urls* is an array of dicts like `{'coordinates': [10, 10, 100, 45], 'url': '0.com'}`. Here is a sample code which produces the following output (as explained above)

```
{'page0': {'emails': [{'email': '0@mail.com'}, {'email': '1@mail.com'}],
       'urls': [{'coordinates': [10, 10, 100, 45], 'url': '0.com'},
                {'coordinates': [10, 10, 100, 45], 'url': '1.com'}]},
 'page1': {'emails': [{'email': '0@mail.com'}, {'email': '1@mail.com'}],
       'urls': [{'coordinates': [10, 10, 100, 45], 'url': '0.com'},
                {'coordinates': [10, 10, 100, 45], 'url': '1.com'}]}}
```

Corresponding python code:

```
import pprint

result = {}
emails_key = "emails"
urls_key = "urls"

for i in range(2):
    page_key = "page" + str(i) 
    result[page_key] = {emails_key: [], urls_key: []}
    for j in range(2):
        result[page_key][emails_key].append({'email': str(j) + '@mail.com'})
        result[page_key][urls_key].append({'url': str(j) + '.com', 'coordinates': [10,10,100,45]})

pprint.pprint(result)
```

Hope this helps.