# How to dynamically create dictionary with array inside of it regardless length of variables needed in array from dataframe?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
NAME           ID
one             1
two             2
three           3
```

I need to create an array that fits this format, where each value in `NAME` gets assigned to `name` in the array. Each record in the dataframe needs its own dictionary:

```
payload = { "tags": [ { "name": "one", "status": "active" },  { "name": "two", "status": "active" } ,  { "name": "three", "status": "active" }] }
```

I also want to dynamically scale the dictionary regardless of the number of records in dataframe. If I have one record in df, then I only need one array.

Comment: status is always active?

Comment: "I also want to dynamically scale the dictionary regardless of the number of records in dataframe." can you explain this please? It seems like `df.assign(status='active')[['NAME', 'status']].to_dict('r')` answers your question but it isn't very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slightly edited [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2468374/10140310), which works great for your case (If I understood correctly)

```py
>>> def gen_name(name):
...   return {"name": name, "status": "active"}
...
>>> payload = {"tags": [gen_name(name) for name in df["NAME"]]}
>>> payload
{'tags': [{'name': 'one', 'status': 'active'}, {'name': 'two', 'status': 'active'}, {'name': 'three', 'status': 'active'}]}
>>
```